# Parse a config-file with Python having more then one variable with the same name

Tags: python-3.x, config, configparser, configobj

Is there a way to parse a config file like this with Python3?

```
path = .MyAppData
prefer = newer
path = Dokumente
```

Please don't blame me. ;) I didn't build the software producing config files like this. But they make sense in that special context.

I know `ConfigParser` and `configobj` for Python3 but don't see a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConfigParser` initialiser supports the `strict=False` argument, which allows duplicates. But which value is retained in that case isn't mentioned in the documentation as far as I can tell.

One simple solution is to convert the lines into a dictionary yourself;

```
In [1]: txt = '''path = .MyAppData
   ...: prefer = newer
   ...: path = Dokumente'''

In [2]: txt.splitlines()
Out[2]: ['path = .MyAppData', 'prefer = newer', 'path = Dokumente']
```

(After splitting the text in lines, you might want to filter out comments and empty lines.)

```
In [3]: [ln.split('=') for ln in txt.splitlines()]
Out[3]: [['path ', ' .MyAppData'], ['prefer ', ' newer'], ['path ', ' Dokumente']]

In [4]: vars = [ln.split('=') for ln in txt.splitlines()]
```

(At this point you might want to add a filter for the inner lists so that you only have lists of length 2, indicating a succesfull split.)

```
In [5]: {a.strip(): b.strip() for a, b in vars}
Out[5]: {'path': 'Dokumente', 'prefer': 'newer'}
```

In the dict comprehension (In [5]), later assignments will override earlier ones.

Of course, if `prefer = older`, you'd have to reverse the lines before the dict comprehension.